# Missing Dictionary<TKey,TValue>.KeyCollection Extension Methods .NET 3.5 (C#)

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

Perhaps I'm missing something with the concept of Extension Methods, but I cannot gain access to the Extension Methods within the KeyCollection Class as defined here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk7e2d8e.aspx.

Using the following code excerpt:

```
   Dictionary<int, int> foo = new Dictionary<int,int>();
   foo.Add(1,1);
   Dictionary<int, int>.KeyCollection kc = foo.Keys;
```

I can only gain access to the "standard" KeyCollection methods (CopyTo, Equals, Finalize, etc) but cannot gain access to the extension methods (Aggregate, All, Any, etc).

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: As an aside, in the documentation for extensions methods as per the link above, you can see the text says: (Defined by Enumerable.) This tells you what class the extension method is in.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just tried it and it looks like I can.

You didn't forget

```
using System.Linq;
```

did you?

Answer (score 2):

Are you missing the `using System.Linq` statement at the top of your class?